# Oracle SQL: Finding common subjects taken by students in each class

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is student table DDL and DML

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
(
  CLASS NUMBER,
  STUDENT_ROLLNO  NUMBER,
  SUBJECT VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 1,'ENGLISH');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 1,  'MATHS');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 1,  'SCIENCE');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 1,  'ART');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 2,  'ENGLISH');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 2,  'MATHS');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 2,  'FRENCH');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 2,  'POETRY');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 3,  'ENGLISH');
INSERT INTO STUDENTS(CLASS, STUDENT_ROLLNO, SUBJECT) VALUES(1, 3,  'MATHS');
```

Now I need to find common subject chosen by each student of that class.
For this case ENGLISH and MATHS would be the result.

I need to write query to fetch the required result as their are more class and result should be as per class.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I could not do anything good in this case

Comment: You can always share what you have tried, even if it is half-complete, or flawed. This way we can assist you better by pointing out the error in the way you try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### try this

```
 WITH SUB1 AS (
SELECT  
CLASS,SUBJECT,COUNT(*) NMB  FROM
STUDENTS
GROUP BY CLASS,SUBJECT
),SUB2 AS(
SELECT CLASS, MAX(NMB)MAX_NMB FROM
(SELECT  
CLASS,COUNT(*) NMB  FROM
STUDENTS
GROUP BY CLASS,SUBJECT
)
GROUP BY CLASS
)
SELECT SUB1.CLASS,SUB1.SUBJECT
FROM SUB1
INNER JOIN SUB2
ON SUB1.NMB=SUB2.MAX_NMB  AND SUB1.CLASS=SUB2.CLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any self-joins:

```
SELECT class,
       subject
FROM   (
  SELECT s.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT student_rollno ) OVER ( PARTITION BY class ) AS num_students
  FROM   students s
)
GROUP BY class, subject
HAVING   COUNT( DISTINCT student_rollno ) = MAX( num_students );
```

**Output**:

```
CLASS SUBJECT
----- -------
    1 ENGLISH
    1 MATHS
```